# Overwrite msg in mirth

Tags: e4x, hl7, mirth

I have two destinations now and the first calls a SOAP webservice.
I want to take the response of that destination by:

```
msg = new XML(responseMap.get('Destination1').getMessage());
```

and convert it to a mutable XML object.
Doing:

logger.error(msg);

```
<S:Body><PRPA_IN201306UV02> ... </PRPA_IN201306UV02></S:Body>
```

Shows the valid msg as I want it, but when I do:

`msg['S:Body']` it returns nothing.

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.S::Body` is what you want. Make sure you define the `S` namespace before you use it.